# Open Multiple vs. Single Instances of a Cocoa App

Tags: cocoa

I've got a script that opens my application using the "open" command.  Right now, open is creating a new instance of my app each time it is called.

What I would like to happen is that open would somehow detect that an instance of my app is already running, and then just send that instance the -(BOOL)application:(NSApplication *)theApplication openFile:(NSString *)fileName message.

I thought that this was the default behavior, but it is apparently not.  Is there a standard way to achieve the behavior I'm looking for?

Here is the script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

ENV['PG_CMD_LINE'] = "true"

app_id = "com.mycom.MyApp"
if ARGV.size > 0
 `open -b #{app_id} #{ARGV[0]}`
else
 `open -b #{app_id} #{Dir.getwd}`
end
```

Is there a relevant portion of the app source code people would like to see?  Otherwise I can code up a demo app.

Comment: That *is* the default behavior. We'll need more information, for example if you could post a sample app and/or the 'open' command line you're using.

Comment: To get the behaviour you see you would normally have to run open -n

Comment: Does this happen with other applications? e.g., if you try "open -b com.apple.textedit somefile.txt" does TextEdit open twice? If not, a demo app would help...

Comment: It seems to have been related to the app having been started in the XCode debugging environment first, then subsequently started from the command line.